# Is there a reason why Israel didn't follow up on its commitment to allow Palestinians in East Jerusalem to participate in voting?

Tags: israel, palestine

> The Palestinian Authority Basic Law provides for an elected president
> and legislative council. There have been no elections in the West Bank
> and Gaza Strip for Palestinian Authority offices since 2006, and
> Palestinians there do not have the right to vote in Israeli elections.
> President Mahmoud Abbas has remained in office despite the expiration
> of his four-year term in 2009. The Palestinian Legislative Council has
> not functioned since 2007, and in 2018 the Palestinian Authority
> dissolved the Constitutional Court. **President Abbas indefinitely
> postponed national elections in April 2021, stating the reason was
> that Israel had not agreed to allow Palestinians in East Jerusalem to
> participate in voting per Israel’s commitment in the Oslo Accords.** The
> Palestinian Authority head of government is Prime Minister Mohammad
> Shtayyeh. President Abbas is also chairman of the Palestine Liberation
> Organization and general commander of the Fatah movement

https://www.state.gov/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/415610_WEST-BANK-AND-GAZA-2022-HUMAN-RIGHTS-REPORT.pdf

President Abbas indefinitely postponed national elections, stating the reason was that Israel had not agreed to allow Palestinians in East Jerusalem to participate in voting despite Israel's own commitment in the Oslo Accords to do so. Is there a reason why Israel didn't follow up on its commitment to allow Palestinians in East Jerusalem to participate in voting? Was any public statement made in regard to this decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Israeli law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_Law), Jerusalem is a sovereign Israeli territory and allowing foreign entities to run elections there would be contrary to that position.

"Oslo Accords" is actually a set of several distinct agreements, so you'll need to refer to the one specifically that you want to rely on. AFAIK, in none of them was there any Israeli commitment with regards to the status of Jerusalem.